# How to install design-time support for Custom User Control Library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-controls

I have a usercontrol library that is no longer supported and want to make some changes to the control code to fix some bugs (I do have the code), but I don't know how to deploy the updated controls to my Visual Studio.  I added the control dll's to the Toolbox and that worked without any issues, but I can't place the controls on the winforms, they just get placed in the tray at the bottom of the designer.

The user controls have separate Design dll's, so it will be Library.Schedule.dll and Library.Schedule.Design.dll.  I presume that the Design dll's are for the design-time support, but I don't know how to install them?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Please refer to: [Walkthrough: Automatically Populating the Toolbox with Custom Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/walkthrough-automatically-populating-the-toolbox-with-custom-components?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), can this solve your issue?

Comment: @WenbinGeng Thank you very much for your response.  I read through that link and it goes over some of the basics with creating a project or adding a control to the Toolbox, but the issue I have is that I've done all of that but the controls still don't have design-time support.  They DO if I use the installer for the control library, but those controls have bugs that I am trying to address.  The dll's that I compile with the fixes don't have design-time support and I'm not sure why. I'm not sure what I'm missing when installing the new dll's. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Remember the last time your control library successfully ran in the operating environment?

Comment: @WenbinGeng Yes, the control library works successfully in the design environment if I install the old version from the installer.  I'm assuming that the installer does something that's registering all of the design-time support or something, but I don't know what it's actually doing or what I may need to do to do that myself.  But the dlls I build, even unchanged, don't have design time support. Do you know why the controls may have different design dll's and how I install or register those?  I think I'm missing a step and I'm not sure where it is honestly.  I appreciate the help though!